# mock Amazon S3 Client for a .NET

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to mock  IAmazonS3 but getting null reference object error, code is below

START:: XUNIT

```
 private readonly Mock<IAmazonS3> _client;  

 public constructor()
 {
     _client = new Mock<IAmazonS3>();
 }

 Stream GivenDocInS3Bucket(string pathToTestDoc)
 {
     var docStream = new FileInfo(pathToTestDoc).OpenRead();
     _client
       .Setup(x => x.GetObjectAsync(
          It.IsAny<string>(),
          It.IsAny<string>(),
          It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
       .ReturnsAsync(
          (string bucket, string key, CancellationToken ct) =>
            new GetObjectResponse
            {
                BucketName = bucket,
                Key = key,
                HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                ResponseStream = docStream,
            });

     return docStream;
 }
```

END:: XUNIT

in Actual file i am getting NUll reference error when calling WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync

```
    var fileObject = await _client.GetObjectAsync(bucketName, decodedFileKey);  
   await fileObject.WriteResponseStreamToFileAsync(tempFilePath, false, CancellationToken.None);
```

Mock in xunit is not working